# Xamarin DACircularProgress component exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use the [DACircularProgress](https://components.xamarin.com/view/DACircularProgress) component from Xamarin, but it doesn't seem to work on a real device.

On the emulator it works well, but on the device the following exception is thrown.

Does anyone know the reason, or used this component successfully?

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.
>
> Native stack trace:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x228bf883  + 150

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34272dff objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x228bf741 <redacted> + 0
3   Foundation                          0x2364f307 <redacted> + 86
4   UIKit                               0x2707ceb5 <redacted> + 480
5   UIKit                               0x2707d45b <redacted> + 14
6   UIKit                               0x26cbbd81 <redacted> + 44
7   UIKit                               0x26b5651f <redacted> + 702
8   UIKit                               0x27078c99 <redacted> + 1220
9   UIKit                               0x2707837b <redacted> + 1234
10  UIKit                               0x26a86847 <redacted> + 30
11  UIKit                               0x26a86823 <redacted> + 30
12  UIKit                               0x26cca889 <redacted> + 52
13  UIKit                               0x26cca805 <redacted> + 252
14  UIKit                               0x269d7243 <redacted> + 30
15  UIKit                               0x26cca6f3 <redacted> + 142
16  UIKit                               0x269ccf9d <redacted> + 1408
17  UIKit                               0x269cccff <redacted> + 738
18  UIKit                               0x269cccff <redacted> + 738
19  UIKit                               0x269cccff <redacted> + 738
20  UIKit                               0x269cccff <redacted> + 738
21  UIKit                               0x269cc471 <redacted> + 124
22  UIKit                               0x269cc317 <redacted> + 426
23  UIKit                               0x269d8de7 <redacted> + 1606
24  UIKit                               0x269d879b <redacted> + 30
25  UIKit                               0x26bbe607 <redacted> + 154
26  UIKit                               0x269ccfb5 <redacted> + 1432
27  UIKit                               0x269cccff <redacted> + 738
28  UIKit                               0x269cc471 <redacted> + 124
29  UIKit                               0x269cc317 <redacted> + 426
30  UIKit                               0x269d8de7 <redacted> + 1606
31  UIKit                               0x269d879b <redacted> + 30
32  UIKit                               0x26c5ab69 <redacted> + 1728
33  UIKit                               0x269dfabd <redacted> + 72
34  UIKit                               0x26bbe191 <redacted> + 180
35  UIKit                               0x26ccacd1 <redacted> + 208
36  UIKit                               0x26bbddcf <redacted> + 966
37  UIKit                               0x26b79c33 <redacted> + 3574
38  UIKit                               0x26a8acd3 <redacted> + 658
39  UIKit                               0x26a8a9dd <redacted> + 52
40  UIKit                               0x26a8a957 <redacted> + 214
41  UIKit                               0x269cd6bb <redacted> + 694
42  QuartzCore                          0x2629967d <redacted> + 128
43  QuartzCore                          0x26294d79 <redacted> + 352
44  QuartzCore                          0x26294c09 <redacted> + 16
45  QuartzCore                          0x26294129 <redacted> + 368
46  QuartzCore                          0x26293deb <redacted> + 590
47  UIKit                               0x269d03f7 <redacted> + 5334
48  CoreFoundation                      0x22882827 <redacted> + 14
49  CoreFoundation                      0x22882417 <redacted> + 454
50  CoreFoundation                      0x2288077f <redacted> + 806
51  CoreFoundation                      0x227d31e9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
52  CoreFoundation                      0x227d2fdd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
53  GraphicsServices                    0x2ba77af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
54  UIKit                               0x26a3818d UIApplicationMain + 144
55  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x005feb08 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 252
56  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x005b581c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 52
57  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x005b57dc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 204
58  libmyappname.exe.dylib                0x0042222c myappname_Application_Main_string__ + 188
59  libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x0082adc8 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 256
60  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0018fea9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1588
61  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x001e37a3 mono_runtime_invoke + 102
62  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x001e6ffb mono_runtime_exec_main + 284
63  libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x003f2408 xamarin_main + 2232
64  myappname                             0x00019677 main + 112
65  libdyld.dylib                       0x3499d873 <redacted> + 2
```